# "The file must have been renamed, moved, or deleted" warning in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, app-store, assets

I have a very basic Android app in Google's Play store. It's basically one window with a webview showing local html content. Most users who download the app have no problems with it. However, a few are not able to use it at all. When they try to open it, they get a warning "The file must have been renamed, moved, or deleted". In other words their phone or tablet can't locate the html files that are packaged together with the app. I can't replicate this problem and have no idea where it's coming from. I wonder if anyone here run into this issue before and resolved it.

For reference, the app design is shown below (nothing special). A bunch of "htm" files is located in "assets". One of them is referenced in the code explicitly - "Contents.htm". There's no css or javascript, but it didn't seem to make any difference as far as this particular error is concerned. This problem is experienced by people outside the US (so far), which may be another clue as to what it could be.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</WebView>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Contents.htm");
    }

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my users finally traced the problem to the app called WPS office. Indeed, when WPS office is installed on a device, my app stops working. Apparently WPS hijacks internal links within android webviews and tries to open them by itself. There are no obvious settings to change that behavior, but after uninstall everything returns to normal. I hope this bit of information may be helpful to someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

WPS office hijacks all links in any webview. You can build a workaround like this:

Write a Javascriptinterface and every link should call a Android-Function which load the specific Webview-Url

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void startGame() {
    mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/game.html");
        }

    });
}
```

With this workaround everything works fine: You can test the workaround in my app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.devbert.circlecommander

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```